# Checksum for a list of numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, checksum

I have a large number of lists of integers. I want to check if any of the lists are duplicates. I was thinking a good way of doing this would be to calculate a basic checksum, then only doing an element by element check if the checksums coincide. But I can't find a checksum algorithm with good properties, namely:

- Verifies order effectively;
- Quick to calculate;
- Returns a small result, eg short integer;
- Has a fairly uniform distribution, giving a low probability of different lists coinciding.

For example, a function check_sum which returned different numbers in the range [0,65536] for the following 5 calls would be ideal.

```
check_sum([1,2,3,4,5])
check_sum([1,2,3,5,4])
check_sum([5,4,3,2,1])
check_sum([1,2,3,4,4])
```

I looked at the IPv4 header checksum algorithm which returns a result of about the right size but doesn't check order so isn't what I'm  looking for.

I'm going to implement it in python, but any format will do for algorithm, or pointer at a good reference material.

Comment: Is `hash( tuple([1,2,3,4,5]) )` not good enough?

Comment: How many lists and how large are they?

Comment: Lists are result of a search algorithm, so I'm trying to stretch the number of lists as far as I can, maybe 100k.  They will be up to 100 long, average 50.

Comment: Given your fairly reasonable wishlist, would a simple Adler-32 not be enough?

Comment: @felih That's not large then. You could just do `len(lists) > len(set(map(tuple, lists)))`. That tells you whether there are any duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the checksums with `hash()`:

```
checksums = \
    list(
        map(
            lambda l:
                hash(tuple(l)),
            list_of_lists
        )
    )
```

To know how many duplicates you have:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(checksums)
```

To compile a unique list:

```
unique_list = list(dict(zip(checksums, list_of_lists)).values())
```

Comment: Why would you write that multi-line `list(map(lambda ... ))` instead of a list comprehension?

Comment: @Stefan you are right, but for me this looks very clear, I see immediately the core and the expression and we don't need to save on lines :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want something homespun, a version of a Fletcher checksum is possible.

```
def check_sum(l):
    sum1 = sum2 = 0
    for v in l:
        sum1 = (sum1 + v) % 255
        sum2 = (sum2 + sum1) % 255
    return sum1*256 + sum2

print(
    check_sum([1,2,3,4,5]),
    check_sum([1,2,3,5,4]),
    check_sum([5,4,3,2,1]),
    check_sum([1,2,3,4,4])
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be mod 256?

```
 def check_sum(l):
    sum1 = sum2 = 0
    for v in l:
        sum1 = (sum1 + v) % 256
        sum2 = (sum2 + sum1) % 256
    return sum1*256 + sum2

print(
    check_sum([1,2,3,4,5]),
    check_sum([1,2,3,5,4]),
    check_sum([5,4,3,2,1]),
    check_sum([1,2,3,4,4])
)
```

Comment: Use use bitwise `& 255`, which doesn't require the interpreter to be smart about `% 256`, if you are doing a lot of this.